# How can i add style from the string html to display in android textview?

Tags: java, android

i have a string html to display in my textview.

```
String html_string = "<p>This is a sample strin</p> <img src=""/>"
```

```
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(html_string, this, null);
        ContentTv.setText(spanned);
        ContentTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); //For the a href to be clickable
```

before i display this on my textview, i want to add width="100%" to the  tag. is this possible in android?

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the textview you can use like this.

```
      <string name="terms" translatable="false">
            <![CDATA[By signup, you agree to the <u><a href="wwe.xyz.com/termsconditions">Terms of Services</a></u> and <u><a href="wwe.xyz.com/privacypolicy.php">Privacy Policy.</a></u>]]></string>

textview.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.terms))
textview.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Otherwise you can use the webview.

```
webview.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");

String yourData =  "<!DOCTYPE html><head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" " +
"content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"> <html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">"+
 "<meta name=\"spanish press\" content=\"spain, spanish newspaper, news,economy,politics,sports\"><title></title></head><body id=\"body\">"+
"<script src=\"http://www.myscript.com/a\"></script>şlkasşldkasşdksaşdkaşskdşk</body></html>";
```